# What is right way to set spf in dns records?

Tags: dns, spf

I'm setting it as: `v=spf1 a mx ip4:xx.xxx.xx.xxx a -mx -all`

it's right?

Thanks.

Comment: i don't know, i'll use it to send authenticated emails, should i use -mx or not?

Answer (score 3):

How you should configure your SPF record depends on what servers you want to allow to send emails on your behalf. However, your example SPF record contains a contradition.  You are specifying both `mx` and `-mx`, meaning you want to both pass and fail if the IP matches an IP address found in the domain's MX records.  You should remove whichever mechanism does not apply.

Without knowing your exact needs it's hard to say exactly what SPF configuration you should use but if I had to take a shot in the dark I would say this is probably a safe bet:

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:xx.xxx.xx.xxx ?all
```

This will pass an email originating form any IP that your domain has an `a` or `mx` record for as well as IP address xx.xxx.xx.xxx. It will apply a status of `neutral` to all others using the `?all` mechanism. This allows spam filters more latitude to determine the validity of the email as opposed to a hard fail (`-all`).

Here are a couple of resource that I think will help you.

[SPF Mehanisms Explained](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)

[SPF Wizard](http://spfwizard.com/)